# Notation Comprehension - Magnetic Field vector

Tags: magnetic-fields

While studying I've come in touch with a question about Magnetic Momentum, Torque and Loops. In it the following picture was given:

[image: A loop in a magnetic field]

During the calculus of the Torque, the intensity of the field and the angle between the loop and the Field is needed, but I did not understand the notation in which the Field intensity is written (B=0,3Tî+0,4Tk^).

It seems it has to do with angles, but the question doesn't mention any of them. The only data I have is the one in the picture aside of the current and the loop sides.

Any idea of what this is about?

Comment: $\hat{i}$ and $\hat{k}$ are sometimes used to denote unit vectors in the $x$- and $z$-directions. Is that your question?

Comment: Yeah, it looks like. Never seen this way of writing vectors before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a very unusual notation. $T$ is Tesla, the unit in which you measure the magnetic induction $B$.
The letters $\hat i$, $\hat j$ and $\hat k$ are sometimes used to denote the unit vectors in the $x$, $y$ and $z$-direction respectively.

So this just means, that the $B$-Field has the value $0.3 T$ in the $x$-direction and $0.4 T$ in the $z$-direction.
I have never seen this mixing of units and vectors before but I'm certain that it is meant this way.

Comment: That actually makes some sense. I'll try to solve the problem with this information. Never heard about this notation and this way to denote unit vectors. Thank you very much.